# Why my PHP script doesn't work in my html ? (i use codeigniter framework)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I put `php` script in my `html` (I use `codeigniter`), but when I show up in localhost, my `php` script eliminate all tag.

I want to put input text box for edit/update something and to show the previous text in my text box. But when I use `php` script, the element (input form and button) in tag php is missing in localhost.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/categories_update'); ?>">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Categories Name</label>

            <?php foreach ($kategori as $k) { ?>

            <input 
                type="hidden" name="id" 
                value="<?php echo base_url().$k->kategori_id; ?>"
            >
            <input 
                type="text" name="categories" 
                value="<?php echo base_url().$k->kategori_nama; ?>" placeholder="Type here. . . "
            >

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="update">
    </div>
</form>
```

This my controller code :

```
    public function categories()
    {
        $this->load->model('m_data');

        $data['kategori'] = $this->m_data->get_data('kategori')->result();
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_header');
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_categories',$data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_footer');
    }

    public function add_categories()
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_header');
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_categories_add');
        $this->load->view('dashboard/v_footer');        
    }

    public function categories_action()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categories','Categories','required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !=false) {
            $categories = $this->input->post('categories');
            $data = array(
                'kategori_nama' => $categories,
                'kategori_slug' => strtolower(url_title($categories))
            );

            $this->load->model('m_data');

            $this->m_data->insert_data($data,'kategori');
            redirect(base_url().'dashboard/categories');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_header');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_categories_add');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_footer');
        }   
    }

    public function categories_edit()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $where = array(
            'kategori_id' => $id
        );

        $this->load->model('m_data');

        $data['kategori']= $this->m_data->edit_data($where,'kategori')->result();
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_header');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_categories_edit',$data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/v_footer');
    }

    public function categories_update()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categories','Categories','required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != false) {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $kategori = $this->input->post('categories');

            $where = array(
                'kategori_id' => $id
            );

            $data = array (
                'kategori_nama' => $kategori,
                'kategori_slug' => strtolower(url_title($kategori))

            );

            $this->load->model('m_data');

            $this->m_data->update_data($where,$data,'kategori');

            redirect(base_url().'dashboard/categories');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering what file extension you use for the script?

Comment: Why not change extension to php? Or you can edit .htaccess or apache config to run php inside html

Comment: i used .php extension for this project

Comment: If you inspect the HTML elements in the browser, do you see the PHP code?

Comment: no, i didn't see the PHP code

Comment: can you show the controller code?

Comment: So then how do you know the PHP isn't working, exactly? What happens on the page (and what should happen)?

Comment: when i show up in localhost, my data doesn't show anything. My tag input is missing.

Comment: i want to show my previous text in the text input tag before we change them. 
but, my input tag is missing, when i put it in php tag script

Comment: what error or objects show after loading controller?

Comment: So you can see the form without PHP code?

Comment: There is no error. Except form with PHP code, all of my script is work.

Comment: @Zendie yes.. i can see the form without PHP code, but when i put PHP code, the form is missing

Comment: what is the name of the view file ?  view file is v_categories.html or v_categories.php?

Comment: v_categories.php

Comment: if (empty($data))
{
    echo "array is empty";
}
else
{
    echo "not empty";
}

Comment: check your data is empty or not

Comment: If you inspect the HTML elements in the browser, do you see the form's HTML & elements?

Comment: i can't see my form element. but i can see the label and anything except the form

Comment: Check your model m_data.php

Comment: your data is empty that's why there is no input field according to your code if data is empty no input field will create .

Comment: there's incorrect script in my controller, 
 before : 
public function categories_edit()
    { $id = $this->input->post('id');
it should be :  public function categories_edit($id)

and now all my script is working ! thankyou bro @RajendraSingh !

Comment: its nice problem getting solved

Answer (score 0):

there's incorrect script in my controller, 
before :

public function categories_edit() {

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

it should be :

public function categories_edit($id)

and now all my script is working ! thankyou guys, especially bro @RajendraSingh !